# Django. edit form field placeholder in view

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I edit the placeholder of a django form field dynamically on a view?

tried this:

```
form = ContactForm()
form.fields['message'].placeholder = "This is a dynamic placeholder"
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do that in your view. Rewrite your `__init__` form method and pass to it your dynamic placeholder.

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    #your form fields

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        placeholder = kwargs.pop("dynamic_placeholder")

        super(CompleteRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['message'].placeholder = placeholder
```

Then in your view.

```
form = ContactForm(dynamic_placeholder='your dynamic placeholder'")
```